# how to configure Apache Camel Quartz endpoint to use JDBCJobStore

Tags: apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I have configured Quartz endpoint for the scheduling requirement. However currently in my route configuration, trigger information is hard coded in the XML configuration file. As per the requirement, trigger information needs to come from DB.

```
<camel:route>
    <camel:from uri="quartz://commandActions/MSFI?cron=15+17+13+?+*+MON-SUN+*" />
    <camel:bean ref="userGateway" method="generateCommand" />
    <camel:to uri="wmq:SU.SCHEDULER" />
</camel:route>
```

Quartz documentation says Jobs and triggers can be stored in database and are accessed using JDBCJobStore. Is it possible to configure Camel Quartz endpoint to use JDBCJobStore? I tried to find out an example but couldn't find. If someone has implemented this before, kindly share an example.

Thanks,
Vaibhav

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yeah see the quartz documentation how to configure it to use a jdbc job store. You can do this using a quartz.properties file, which you can tell Camel to use.

See the Camel side part here: http://camel.apache.org/quartz at the section *Configuring quartz.properties file*

Comment: Thanks Claus. I could setup quartz to use jdbcjobstore. Now my camel route config looks like  `<camel:route>
   <camel:from uri="quartz://commandActions/MSFI" />
   <camel:bean ref="userGateway"/>
   <camel:to uri="wmq:SU.SCHEDULER" />
  </camel:route> <bean id="quartz" class="org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.QuartzComponent">
     <property name="propertiesFile" value="quartz.properties"/>
 </bean>`. However it seems quartz is starting simple trigger for above configuration. The above route sends message after 1 minute from application startup. Kindly let me know what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Configure the quartz uri in the from to use cron/simple trigger as you want, see the Camel docs for examples/options you can use.